# Custom category Image attribute Magento 2.3+

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, image-upload, magento-admin

I've searched alot and evrywhere the code has to go through many plugins and need of adding routers to add custom image attribute for category. I've added a code below to add custom image attribute which is completely hassel-free and hope it helps someone.

Note: **It's tested and verified on Magento 2.3.5**

*Considering the module exists already*

1. Add image attribute install code to setup

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php 

declare(strict_types=1);


namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'custom_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Navigation Thumbail Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => 0,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

2. To show custom image attribute on admin category form

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general" sortOrder="10">
        <field name="custom_image" sortOrder="10" formElement="imageUploader">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Custom Image</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <required>false</required>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <imageUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <required>false</required>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="catalog/category_image/upload"/>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                        <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                        <openDialogTitle>Media Gallery</openDialogTitle>
                        <initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>catalog/category</initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>
                        <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                        <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
                    </settings>
                </imageUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

That's it. run upgrade **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** and clear cache **php bin/magento cache:flush**. The newly added category image attribute would show as shown below.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain in details what problem you face.

Comment: @Msquare I explained the fix for a problem I've faced.

Comment: I can't explain why your solution does not have more upvotes. You're the best.